# Admin user getting redirected to /wp-admin/user

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, redirect, login, network-admin

I recently added a network to my multi-network wordpress install (that is, a single install with multiple subdomain networks, each with multiple subdirectory sites).

Although everything appears normal on the new site from the front end and network admin view, any users I add to the site automatically get redirected to `/wp-admin/user` upon login. This shows only the WordPress news widget and the Profile menu.

If I manually navigate back to `/wp-admin`, the full dashboard becomes available, but the redirect is unacceptably inconvenient and hard to diagnose.

A few details that are unique and likely relevant:

- When creating the new subdomain, I first created a blog on an existing network, then manually went in and modified `wp_sites` and `wp_blogs` to promote it to its own subdomain
- I recently upgraded to 3.9.2
- This only affects the new subdomain. All existing sites and networks are fine (ruling out plugin conflicts or a botched upgrade in my eyes)

I am relatively certain this problem is probably just one or two database rows away from a fix, but laboriously comparing the values of `wp_sitemeta` and `wp_*_options` for a working network to this one reveals nothing different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although why it happened isn't obvious, the problem was that the new users were missing `wp_*_capabilities` rows for the affected site in the `wp_usermeta` table.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior for WordPress. As with most things in WordPress, there is a plugin for what you are trying to do. Try this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/

Comment: This is not normal behavior; I think that maybe you got my question backwards? The system is _automatically_ sending admin users to **/wp-admin/user/** instead of /wp-admin/.

Answer (score 0):

this have been dead for 8 years, but it showed in my googleing for a solution so if anyone comes here having a problem with login redirecting wp-admin/user on multisites.

the problem is user_admin_url() function in wp-includes/link-template.php
this is only used on multisites.

my fix

```
add_filter("user_admin_url",function($url){
    return str_replace("/user","",$url);
});
```